# How to select / join some data from one mySQL innodb table to another with no duplicates and choosing the last inserted row per id

Tags: mysql, join, view

I'm new to mySQL, and I'm trying to be able to either ***SELECT*** or ***CREATE A VIEW***  with the information I want to retrieve from two tables. [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8652/2/0)

***People Table***

```
| people_id | username  | Password  | Email  |
----------------------------------------------
|     1     | username1 | Password1 | Email1 |
|     2     | username2 | Password2 | Email2 |
|     3     | username3 | Password3 | Email3 |
```

***Profile Table***

```
| people_id | id | age  | location |        hobbies                 |                         about                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1     | 1  |  22  |   USA    |  skiing, snowboarding          |   I am from the US and I like to snowboard           |
|     2     | 2  |  45  |  Canada  |  curling, ice skating, reading |   I like to ice skate!                               |
|     3     | 3  |  38  |   USA    |  tv, movies, you name it       |   I am from the US and I like to watch the tube      |
|     2     | 4  |  45  |  Canada  |  curling, reading              |   I do not like to ice skate anymore                 |
|     2     | 5  |  46  |  Canada  |  bowling                       | Bowling is my new favorite hobby! I just turned 46!  |
|     1     | 6  |  22  |  Brazil  |  skiing, snowboarding          | I am orginally from the US but I just moved to brazil|
```

***I would like to see/retrieve the data like this :***

```
| people_id | username   | age  | location |        hobbies                 |                         about                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     3     | username3  |  38  |   USA    |  tv, movies, you name it       |   I am from the US and I like to watch the tube      |
|     2     | username2  |  46  |  Canada  |  bowling                       | Bowling is my new favorite hobby! I just turned 46!  |
|     1     | username1  |  22  |  Brazil  |  skiing, snowboarding          | I am orginally from the US but I just moved to brazil|
```

So I need to select all the `people_id` and `username` from table `People` and then select the `people_id` row from `Profile` where the `id` is the largest number for each `people_id`

I've tried

```
SELECT People.people_id, People.username, Profile.age, Profile.location, Profile.hobbies, Profile.about
FROM People
INNER JOIN Profile
ON People.people_id=Profile.people_id
```

Which gets me closer to what I want, but I don't want to show duplicate rows, I only want to show the last row inserted into the Profile table for each `people_id`.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8652/2/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to get what you want is to use a `not exists` condition in the `where` clause.  This definitely takes some getting used to.  What the query is going to do is to get the matching row from `Profile` subject to the condition that no other row has a larger `id`.  This is a round-about way of saying "get the biggest `id` for each person".  But, it happens to produce an efficient query plan (and this is true in most databases, not just MySQL).

```
SELECT p.people_id, p.username, pr.age, pr.location, pr.hobbies, pr.about
FROM People p INNER JOIN
     Profile pr
     ON p.people_id = pr.people_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Profile pr2
                  WHERE pr2.people_id = pr.people_id AND
                        pr2.id > pr.id
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT People.people_id, People.username, Profile.age, Profile.location, Profile.hobbies, Profile.about
FROM People
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Profile ORDER BY id DESC) AS Profile
ON People.people_id=Profile.people_id
GROUP BY People.people_id
ORDER BY people_id DESC
```